# Getting a null-point exception in Neo4j data retrieval

Tags: java, database, neo4j

I have the following code.

```
GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
GraphDatabaseService db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/Users/shadid/Documents/Neo4j/DB");

ExecutionEngine execEngine = new ExecutionEngine(db, null);
ExecutionResult execResult = execEngine.execute("MATCH (mat:TheMatrix) RETURN mat");
String results = execResult.dumpToString();
System.out.println(results);
```

I am getting a null point exception. I have tried running the command in the neo4j command line. So the data do exist. I am not quite sure where is the error. Quite a noob in neo4j so could someone please help me out

Here's the error I am getting by the way

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.CypherCompiler.(CypherCompiler.scala:69)
>   at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.createCompiler(ExecutionEngine.scala:237)
>   at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.(ExecutionEngine.scala:64)
>   at App.Main.main(Main.java:53)

Answer (score 0):

Just found a more intuitive way of doing the same thing and it works yay!!!

```
try ( Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();
                  Result result = db.execute( "MATCH (n:TheIronGiant) RETURN n.`title: `" ) )
            {
            String rows ="";
            while ( result.hasNext() )
                {
                    Map<String,Object> row = result.next();

                    for ( Entry<String,Object> column : row.entrySet() )
                    {
                        rows  += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
                    }
                    rows += "\n";
                }
            System.out.println(rows);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using the [ExecutionEngine constructor](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionEngine.html#ExecutionEngine(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService,%20org.neo4j.logging.LogProvider)) that takes a `LogProvider` as the second parameter, but passing a `null` value for it. If you called the [single-parameter constructor](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionEngine.html#ExecutionEngine(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService)) instead, which does not take a `LogProvider`, you may not get the exception.
2. Also, [ExecutionEngine class](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionEngine.html) is now deprecated, and you should use [GraphDatabaseService.execute()](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#execute(java.lang.String)) instead.